# rendering 1 million boxes in react-three/fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, webgl, react-three-fiber

I am testing the rendering 1 mil boxes in react-three/fiber. The performance is very slow.

```
function App() {
  const boxes = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    const x = Math.random();
    const y = Math.random();
    const z = Math.random();

    const box = (
      <mesh position={[x, y, z]}>
        <boxGeometry args={[0.01, 0.01, 0.01]} />
        <meshLambertMaterial color={"red"} />
      </mesh>
    );

    boxes.push(box);
  }

  return (
    <MBox style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}>
      <Canvas camera={{ position: [10, 10, 10] }}>
        <pointLight position={[15, 15, 15]} />
        {boxes}
        <OrbitControls />
        <Stats />
      </Canvas>
    </MBox>
  );
}
```

[image]

The render is responsive with 1000 boxes (60 FPS). With 10000 boxes, it drops to 7 FPS with a bit lack. The browser dies with 100000 boxes.

The computer dedicated GPU NVIDIA is not utilized at all.
[image]

Any idea to improve the performance please?

Comment: You should consider to render your boxes with [InstancedMesh](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=instanced#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh).

Comment: Not sure still can use InstancedMesh if each box will has diferrent width, height, depth in my case.

Comment: This could be implemented via different scales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with @Mugen87 advice.

```
function Boxes() {
  const meshRef = useRef<InstancedMesh>();
  const tempObject = new Object3D();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (meshRef == null) return;
    if (meshRef.current == null) return;

    let i = 0;
    for (let x = 0; x < 100; x++)
      for (let y = 0; y < 100; y++)
        for (let z = 0; z < 100; z++) {
          const id = i++;
          tempObject.position.set(x, y, z);
          tempObject.scale.set(1, 0.5, 1.5);
          tempObject.updateMatrix();
          meshRef.current.setMatrixAt(id, tempObject.matrix);
        }
    meshRef.current.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;
  }, []);

  return (
    <instancedMesh ref={meshRef} args={[null as any, null as any, 1000000]}>
      <boxGeometry args={[0.1, 0.1, 0.1]}></boxGeometry>
      <meshBasicMaterial />
    </instancedMesh>
  );
}
```